Schedule wakeup with WinAPI in Rust
I'm trying to write alarm clock program that will wakeup the computer at specific time from hibernation/sleep or shutdown and make the alarm sound.
I created the following functions:
use crate::args::Args;
use eyre::Result;
use std::time::Duration;

#[cfg(windows)]
pub fn scheduled_wakeup(schedule: Duration) -> Result<()> {
  use windows::Win32::Foundation::HANDLE;
  use windows::Win32::System::Threading::{
    CreateWaitableTimerW, SetWaitableTimer, WaitForSingleObject, INFINITE,
  };

  // Due time in 100-nanosecond intervals (negative for relative time)
  let due_time = -(schedule.as_secs() as i64 * 10_000_000);
  unsafe {
    let timer: HANDLE = CreateWaitableTimerW(None, true, None)?;
    SetWaitableTimer(
      timer, &due_time, 0, // One-time timer
      None, None, true, // Resume from sleep
    )?;
    WaitForSingleObject(timer, INFINITE);
  };
  Ok(())
}

With the following dependencies:
windows = { version = "0.58.0", features = [
    "Win32",
    "Win32_Security",
    "Win32_System",
    "Win32_System_Threading",
] }

But when I run the program and turn it into sleep mode, it doesn't turn on after a minute.
Also, how can I do it in a way that the event will be declared as "important" so it will work if the power setting was set like that? -

I can see that it scheduled in
powercfg -waketimers

But still, it doesn't turn on the PC

From SetWaitableTimer: "Timers are initially inactive. To activate a timer, call SetWaitableTimer."

I call it, you can see in the code I attached

That, too, is explained in the documentation: "If relative time is specified, the timer does not include time spent in low-power states. For example, the timer does not continue counting down while the computer is asleep." You'll have to specify an absolute time as the due time.

I can see that the due time is correct using powercfg /waketimers
The issue is that for some reason the timer is not flagged as wake up timer. eg. when I compare it with the result of powercfg /waketimers after setting scheduled task to wakeup the computer from task scheduler (which works even in hibernation)

Have you tried specifying a time point rather than a duration, i.e., an absolute time vs. a relative time? You can use Instant::now() and Add a Duration. Though I don't know how to get a FILETIME out of an Instant. Rust's std::time is incredibly incomplete.

Turns out the code works. I needed to enable non important timers to wakeup the computer by opening control powercfg.cpl,,3 -> Sleep -> Allow wake timers -> Enable instead of Important only.
I'm wondering now how can I configure the timer to be considered as important

Turns out the code works. I needed to enable non important timers to wakeup the computer by opening control powercfg.cpl,,3 -> Sleep -> Allow wake timers -> Enable instead of Important only. I'm wondering now how can I configure the timer to be considered as important
